# Prove that $PT$ bisects $\angle{ATB}$ with two touching circles.

Tags: circles

I'm having some trouble figuring out this apparently easy question:

[image]

Two circles touch internally at $T$. $TP$ is a chord of the smaller circle and the tangent at $P$ cuts the larger circle at $A$ and $B$ respectively. Prove that $PT$ bisects $\angle{ATB}$.

My current idea is to prove that $\triangle{APT}$ and $\triangle{BPT}$ are similar, however I cannot figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You have to argue with angles and not with similarity. What can you say about $\Delta QTP$ and what about $QT$ and $QP$?

[image]

I'll can add more information if necessary.